# Extract values from String using Python

Tags: python

I am getting a string

```
name="Mathew",lastname="Thomas",zipcode="PR123T",gender="male"
```

I need to get the values `Mathew, Thomas, PR123T, male`.

Also if the String doesnt have a value for zipcode, it should not assign any value to string.

I am newbie to python. Please help

Comment: Can you post the exact input you get? Here you have just posted some variable assignments.

Comment: can you copy paste exactly what you're getting? what youve written here forces us to guess whether its all really strings with quotes inside or separate variables or whatnot

Comment: Thats the exact ouput I am getting @Jay

Comment: I havent written any regex, but confused how to get the value @ParitoshSingh

Comment: Can you like post your code? It gets really difficult to understand your prooblem if you just post your problem statement and no context.

Comment: You've been a member for 7+ years, surely you know by now that it's a good idea to post the code you've already tried? And, if you have no code, surely you know SO is not a "write my code for me" website :-)

Comment: if i copy paste your given line as-is, python will spit it out as syntax error. What is the real data/content you're getting that python is holding/displaying?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `.split()` function that is available on every string. First you need to split by comma `,`, then you need to split by `=` and select the 1th element.

Once this is done, you need to `.join()` the elements on a comma `,` again.

```py
def split_my_fields(input_string):
    if not 'zipcode=""' in input_string:
        output = ', '.join(e.split('=')[1].replace('"','') for e in input_string.split(','))
        print(f'Output is {output}')
        return output
    else:
        print('Zipcode is empty.')

split_my_fields(r'name="Mathew",lastname="Thomas",zipcode="PR123T",gender="male"')
```

Output:

```py
>>> split_my_fields(r'name="Mathew",lastname="Thomas",zipcode="PR123T",gender="male"')
Output is Mathew, Thomas, PR123T, male
'Mathew, Thomas, PR123T, male'
```

Comment: you basically copied my answer after criticizing it

Comment: I meant no offense @dd95. If you check [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) (the Answer question) section it says *"Read the question carefully. What, **specifically**, is the question asking for?."* and *"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."*. I used the input from the question, you used the output as the input instead. I posted an answer that can be copy-pasted and works, yours is an explanation of how join and split functions work. I'm really sorry if you took this personally, it was not the intent.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, my dear friend, you can use [parse](https://github.com/r1chardj0n3s/parse)

```
>>from parse import *
>>parse("name={},lastname={},zipcode={},gender={}","name='Mathew',lastname='Thomas',zipcode='PR123T',gender='male'")
<Result ("'Mathew'", "'Thomas'", "'PR123T'", "'male'") {}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use named groups and create dictionary with keys corresponding to the group names:

```
import re

text = 'name="Mathew",lastname="Thomas",zipcode="PR123T",gender="male"'
expr = re.compile(r'^(name="(\s+)?(?P<name>.*?)(\s+)?")?,?(lastname="(\s+)?(?P<lastname>.*?)(\s+)?")?,?(zipcode="(\s+)?(?P<zipcode>.*?)(\s+)?")?,?(gender="(\s+)?(?P<gender>.*?)(\s+)?")?$')

match = expr.search(text).groupdict()

print(match['name'])      # Matthew
print(match['lastname'])  # Thomas
print(match['zipcode'])   # R123T
print(match['gender'])    # male
```

The pattern will catch all non-whitespace characters between parentheses and strip whitespaces around it. For empty `zipcode` value it will return an empty string (the same applies for other named groups). It will also handle missing key-value pairs as long as the order in which keys are appearing will stay the same (e.g. `text = 'name="Mathew",lastname="Thomas",gender="male"'`).

Comment: Thanks @machnic, could you help with one more case, consider in one scenario, Zipcode is not present at all, or lastname is not present at all. So how can we check if that zipcode or name or gender key is present or not. If present then extract its value. Like that way ?

Comment: This is already done in the example above, isn't it? If the value was not provided for any of them, then you have an empty string assigned to the corresponding key in the `match` dictionary.

Comment: @mechnic, but if the text is text = 'name="Mathew",lastname="Thomas",gender="male"'. Then it is throwing error. there are only 4 keys : name, lastname, gender and zipcode. but there can be chances if some keys wont appear at all. So can we check if each key is present the get its value

Comment: I modified the pattern to cover your example. It will work as long as the order in which the keys are present in the string will stay the same. It doesn't matter how many of them will be skipped but keep in mind that skipped ones won't be present in the dictionary. You will need to handle missing keys separately.